# Solve the recurrence $T(n)=T(n-3)+\frac1{\log n}$

Tags: recurrence-relations

We must solve the recurrence $T(n)=T(n-3)+ \frac{1}{\log {n}}$ using substitution.
I've got up to here
$$T(n)=T(n-3-3)+\frac1{\log(n-3)} + \frac1{\log n} \implies T(n-3-3-3) + \frac1{\log(n-3-3)} + \frac1{\log(n-3)} + \frac1{\log n}$$

And after $k$ steps

$$\begin{split}
T(n)&=T(n-3k)+\frac1{\log(n-3(k-1))}+\cdots+\frac1{\log(n-3(0))}\\
&=T(n-3k)+\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\frac{1}{\log{(n-3i)}}\\ 
\end{split}$$

But I don't know how to approximate or solve the $\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\frac{1}{\log{(n-3i)}}$, what can I do next?

Comment: What's your initial condition?

Comment: We must establish it ourselves, I was planning to use T(0)=1 in order to have n=3k and have the T(n-3k)=T(0)=1

Comment: What is the base of `log`? You can't use `T(0)=1` because `log 0` is undefined

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. I rather doubt there's a closed form solution. Note that an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24T(n)%3DT(n-3)%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Clog%20n%7D%24&p=1) result includes [Asymptotic of $T(n) = T(n-2) + \frac{1}{ \lg n}$](/q/194510), [Find asymptotic behavior of recurrence $T(n) =T(n-2) + 1/\ln n$](/q/1153382) and [Time Complexity of $T(n)=T(n-2)+\frac{1}{\log(n)}$](/q/167418), where all $3$ posts use a fairly minor variation of your recursive equation, but they each ask to only find the asymptotic behavior.

Comment: It's a log base 2